# Where can I find the Nautilus default icons?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, icons

I want to change the color of the back and forward icons in Nautilus but I can't find them anywhere.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with Radiance theme (I want to change the orange arrows). I looked in the Radiance theme icons folder but didn't find them there. I've looked in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/`, `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/`, and `/usr/share/pixmaps`.

They seem to be system default icons but I have no idea where they could be hiding... Anyone??

Comment: why don't you just use a different theme?,and the nautilus arrows , change when using a different icon theme so you would have to change that-

Answer (score 1):

The icons you seek are called 'go-previous.svg' and 'go-next.svg' and are located in /usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions.